# Space opera book series about an augmented soldier doing a planetary assist toward Uranus to kill cyborgs

Tags: story-identification, books, space-opera

I am a die hard sci-fi space opera reader. I read an ongoing series that was a work in progress about 5 years ago. This was a series of books, each about 300-400 pages long. There were 4-8 books in this series. The author was not someone who most people would recognize (i.e. Asimov, Robinson, etc.).

The premise of the books is that there are a group of normal humans. There are also some cyborgs (which they defined as mostly machine). The cyborgs are most definitely evil. The main character takes part in battle after battle - all centered in Earth's solar system. None of the parts I got up to took place outside of the solar system.

There is one scene in one of the books where they take part in a denial of space strategy by releasing huge clouds of dust moving at relativistic speeds toward enemy ships. The dust obliterates the ships. Behind the cloud of dust is our main character (Marvin?? - Can't recall!). His ship is badly damaged (or destroyed, and he's in a space suit). He's been able to do a gravity assist off a planet and is on his way to kill the main cyborg hideout on Uranus.

There's also secondary hide outs on various asteroids in the solar system - especially some that are further out. There's another scene where a missile blows up one of those asteroids.

I read most of the books in this series online. I can't find the books anymore - I want to make sure that I finished reading all of them.

Any ideas? Thanks for looking!

A couple other details

- English language
- No hard copy available AFAIK
- Space opera
- At least 3-4 books in the series. Maybe as many as 8.
- Written within the last 5-7 years
- Not a famous author

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not a perfect match, but from what I can find online, this is quite similar to the [*Doom Star* series](https://www.goodreads.com/series/61422-doom-star) by Vaughn Heppner.  It's a couple of years earlier, 2010-2014, but at 6.5 books it's close to what you're looking for.  According to [ISFDb](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pe.cgi?37118) the main series books are between 320 and 380 pages.

The series' hero is Marten Kluge, a normal human caught in a multi-way war between baseline humans, genetically modified transhumans and cyborgs.  Even as he moves from planet to planet and faction to faction through the books it seems he's always getting sucked into battles.  The cyborgs really show up in book 4 [*Cyborg Assault*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12101696-cyborg-assault) and become the main antagonists.  The cyborgs come from Neptune though, not Uranus.

I haven't read these, so I can't confirm the specific scenes you recall, but in all other respects these are very close to what you've described.

Comment: This was it!! Thank you so much for your help finding this.